# Camel XML Security Sign component not adding KeyValue tag within KeyInfo tag under Signature element

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, apache-camel

We are trying to generate a signed SOAP XML where <*ds:Signature*> element should be added under <*Soap:Header*> element.

We are able to generate the Signature tag as expected but under <*ds:KeyInfo*> element <*ds:KeyValue*> is not getting generated.

Below is the code snippet for reference:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    Registry registry = getCamelContext().getRegistry();
    DefaultKeyAccessor defaultKeyAccessor = new DefaultKeyAccessor();
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream("<path to keystore.jks>"),"<keystore_password>".toCharArray());
    defaultKeyAccessor.setKeyStore(ks);
    defaultKeyAccessor.setPassword("<keystore_password>");
    defaultKeyAccessor.setAlias("<keystore_alias>");
    registry.bind("accessor", defaultKeyAccessor);
    from("direct:enveloping")
            .to("xmlsecurity-sign://enveloped?keyAccessor=#accessor&parentLocalName=Header&parentNamespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" +
                    "&signatureAlgorithm=http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1")
            .log("reached to xmlsecurity-sign ,${body} ");

}
```

Actual <*ds:KeyInfo*> element in generated signed XML is:

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509SubjectName>...</ds:X509SubjectName>
    <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
```

</ds:KeyInfo>

Expected <*ds:KeyInfo*> element in generated signed XML is:

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509SubjectName>...</ds:X509SubjectName>
    <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
<ds:KeyValue>
    <ds:RSAKeyValue>
        <ds:Modulus>...</ds:Modulus>
        <ds:Exponent>...</ds:Exponent>
    </ds:RSAKeyValue>
</ds:KeyValue>
```

</ds:KeyInfo>

Could you please suggest if anything is missed in the above code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any suggestion with regards to above query is much appreciated.